# Creating hyperplane for a set of points

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

I am trying to solve the equation for local approximating hyperplane in [this](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~levin/mls03cor.pdf) paper {page 6}.

Plane Equation is : $ H_r = \{ x | \langle a, x \rangle - D = 0 \}  $

$ ||a|| = 1 $

$ q = r + ta$

$ E(a,q) = \sum_{i\in I} (\langle a, r_{i} \rangle - D) ^ 2 \theta(||r_i-q||) $

$ \frac{\partial E}{\partial a} = 2\sum_{i\in I} r_i (\langle a,r_i \rangle -D) \theta(||r_i-q||) = 0 $

$ \sum_{i\in I} r_i . a . r_i \theta(||r_i - r - ta ||) = D \sum_{i\in I} r_i \theta(||r_i - r - ta||)$ (1)

$ \frac{\partial E}{\partial D} = -2\sum_{i\in I} (\langle a,r_i \rangle -D) \theta(||r_i-q||) = 0$

$ \sum_{i\in I} a.r_i \theta(||r_i - r - ta||) = D\sum_\theta(||r_i-r-ta) $ (2)

I differentiated the energy equation to get the Normal equation as solved [here](http://www.nealen.com/projects/mls/asapmls.pdf), but I have both `a` and `D` as variables in equations (1) and (2). So, I can't get an equation with form such that `a` is made of only known variables {$ r_i, r, \theta $}. How do I solve this equation to get the set $ \{ a, D \}$ or $\{a,t\}$?

Comment: What is $r_i.a.r_i$?

Comment: I just opened the bracket after the differential. It's the product of these vectors.

Comment: Not a good idea. Better to leave it as a scalar product times a vector.

Comment: I can get the $a$ vector out of that product as it is not dependent of $i$ from sigma. But the real problem is the weight function $\theta(||r_i - r - ta||)$, where I need the value of a.